# jQuery hidden element still shows border

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a field which I will either `.show()` or `.hide()` via jQuery Mobile. When shown the field looks like it should:

[image: shown]

But when I call `.hide()`, you can still see what looks like the border of the elements as below:

[image]

How can I hide this element completely?

Comment: If you are able to, use the browsers developer tools to inspect the line that is remaining after the .hide() and see if it is a container around the element.

Comment: With the hide function the textbox does completely disappeared then this line is for another reasons. please post your codes or a demo link.

Comment: jQM creates a parent DIV with borders around the input.  You could show and hide the parent: $("#txtEmail").parent("div").hide(); or destroy and recreate the widget:  $("#txtEmail").textinput( "destroy" ).hide(); / $("#txtEmail").show().textinput(  );

Comment: @Brad have you fix this?

Comment: Thanks guys, @ezanker your fix was perfect. `$("#selector").parent().hide();` did the trick nicely.